# A different proof for KL divergence non-negativity

Tags: mathematical-statistics, logarithm, kullback-leibler, inequality

KL divergence's non-negativity can be proved in many ways. One could use the inequality $\log x \leq x - 1$ as a main step in the proof, another one could leverage the property of concave of the logarithm function to yield the non-negativity.

Although those proofs are concise and simple, I found they less obvious to come up with, particularly, for one who is not familiar with concavity and inequality.

Therefore, I am trying to find an alternative proof which doesn't require knowledge of logarithm inequality as well as concavity.

The following is what I've come up with:

$KL(p||q)\geq0$

$\Leftrightarrow\sum_i p_i \ln p_i \geq \sum_i p_i\ln q_i$

$\Leftrightarrow\sum_i \ln p_i^{p_i} \geq \sum_i p_i\ln q_i^{p_i}$

$\Leftrightarrow e^{\sum_i \ln p_i^{p_i}} \geq e^{\sum_i p_i\ln q_i^{p_i}}$

$\Leftrightarrow e^{\ln p_1^{p_1}}...e^{\ln p_n^{p_n}} \geq e^{\ln q_1^{p_1}}...e^{\ln q_n^{p_n}}$

$\Leftrightarrow  p_1^{p_1}...p_n^{p_n} \geq  q_1^{p_1}... q_n^{p_n}$

Constrains: $0\leq p_i,q_i \leq 1$ and $\sum_i p_i=1$ and $\sum_i q_i=1$

To prove that $KL(p||q)\geq0$ , now I need to prove that:

$  p_1^{p_1}...p_n^{p_n} \geq  q_1^{p_1}... q_n^{p_n}$ $(*)$

Hopefully, $(*)$ is simpler to prove in terms of not using logarithm function. However, I am stuck here.

I would appreciate any idea helps to prove $(*)$ or corrections for the transformation (if any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(\boldsymbol{q})=f(q_1,q_2,...,q_{n-1})=q_1^{p_1}q_2^{p_2}...q_{n-1}^{p_{n-1}}(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{q_i})^{1-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}p_i}$. I just removed $p_n$, $q_n$ because they depend on other $p_i,q_i$. Here, we know $p_i$, and we try to maximize $f(\boldsymbol{q})$. In the end, we'll see that it's going to be maximized when $p_i=q_i$.

$$\frac{\partial f(\boldsymbol{q})}{\partial q_i}=p_iq_i^{p_i-1}(1-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{q_k})^{1-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}p_k}-q_i^{p_i}(1-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{q_k})^{-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}p_k}=0$$

Solving this yields $p_iq_n=q_1p_n$. Writing this for all $i$ in $1,2,...n-1$, yields $p_i=q_i$ via some algebra. So, any choice of $q_i$ other than $p_i$ yields a smaller $f(\boldsymbol{q})$. Leaving to prove that this is actually maximum to you.